# Wcf Json Post works in VS but not in IIS 7.5

Tags: json, wcf, iis, rest, post

I have a partially working WCF Service in IIS.  My GET requests are working fine but POSTS only work when I am in Visual Studio.  When I use IIS I get Error 400 Bad Request.  Can anyone help to troubleshoot this.  Here is some of the code.

### Class

```
public string AddHost(Host host)
{
    HostDal dal = new HostDal();
    dal.CreateHost(host);
    return Utils.Message;
}
```

### Interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/addhost", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string AddHost(Host host);
```

Using Fiddler I am posting json like this:

{
"Name":"newhost19",
"Mac":"ca:99:11:22:33:43",
"Image":"test",
"Group":"test",
"Description":"test",
"Kernel":"test",
"BootImage":"test",
"Args":"test",
"Scripts":"test"
}

Like I said If I post to **http://localhost/web/ClientSvc.svc/addhost** using IIS I get error 400.
If I post to **http://localhost:49807/web/ClientSvc.svc/addhost** using VS It works fine
Thanks

Comment: When you go to http://localhost/web/ClientSvc.svc do you see a service annoucement page?

Comment: Yes.  It is strange because the service is working.  I also have some GETS that work fine.  It is only the POSTS that don't.

Comment: If anyone is interested, it ended up being a folder permission problem.  I'm still not sure why GETS worked.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, it ended up being a folder permission problem. I'm still not sure why GETS worked